# Как переделать полную идентификацию виртуального поля в GridView на короткую?

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Есть `GridView`, которая загружает провайдер данных некой модели `Test`.

В модели прописан геттер:

```
/***
 * @return string Идентификатор объекта
 */
public function getIdentifier() {
    return $this->type . $this->code . $this->number;
}
```

Если записать в `GridView` вот так:

```
<?= GridViewAdvanced::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $testDataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Идентификатор',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->identifier;
            }
        ],      
    ],
]); ?>
```

Всё прекрасно отображается.

Однако я хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было обратиться лишь по имени, как если бы это было поле из БД и чтоб эффект был аналогичен. Пример:

```
<?= GridViewAdvanced::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $testDataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'name',
        'date',
        'identifier' // вот тут значение моего виртуального поля
    ],
]); ?>
```

Если я просто в модели создаю `public $identifier;` и в `attributeLabels` прописываю значение, то мне просто выводит пустое значение. А хотелось бы то, что вычисляется.

Можно ли это как-то сделать? Как?

Comment: А если создать свойство `public $ident;`, а в конструкторе или в ините заполнить это свойство `$this->ident = $this->identifier;`? Или может в каком-то методе, который вызывается после выполнения запроса.

Comment: @fedornabilkin "может в каком-то методе, который вызывается после выполнения запроса" --- вот интересно тогда каком)  А если делать в `init` то по итогу ничего нет, что, наверное, логично, потому что данные загружаются в модель именно после запроса или после какого-нибдуь `$model->load` и т.д.

Comment: `afterFind()` есть метод, его можно использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При наличии атрибута `public $identifier;` надо немного изменить геттер:

```
public function getIdentifier()
{
    $this->identifier = $this->type . $this->code . $this->number;

    return $this->identifier;
}
```

Но более правильно будет вообще убрать атрибут `public $identifier;` и оставить ваш геттер как есть. Тогда он будет автоматически срабатывать при любом обращении к атрибуту.

Единственное, вам придётся указывать `label` в `GridView`, но это можно делать сокращённым синтаксисом: `attribute:format:label`. Т.е. в вашем примере это будет выглядеть так:

```
<?= GridViewAdvanced::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $testDataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'name',
        'date',
        'identifier:text:Идентификатор'
    ],
]); ?>
```

Подробнее про вывод колонок - [тут](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$columns-detail).

Comment: Попробовал даже без сокращённого синтаксиса вывода колонок, добавив имя геттера в `attributeLabels` и тоже работает. Хотел конечно с виртуальным полем, потому что так было бы нагляднее для остальных программистов, что оно есть. Это скорее единственная причина была его заводить. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Хотя метод с чуть переписанным геттером не работает)

Comment: @СергейМишин Рад, что чем-то помог :)
Геттеры и сеттеры - это вполне очевидные методы в Yii. Любой геттер автоматически является как бы атрибутом ActiveRecord. Для наглядности и подсветки просто вынесите его в phpDoc модели.

Comment: @СергейМишин вариант с afterFind() тоже будет работать. Однако, вы можете столкнуться с небольшими сложностями, если будете делать фильтр по этому полю, т.к. в поисковой модели оно у вас будет получаться всегда предварительно заполненным.

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов: добавить в метод модели `afterFind` определение/переопределение виртуального поля:

```
class MyClass extends ActiveRecord {

    public $testField = 'my value';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'testField' => 'моё вирт. поле'
        ];
    }

    public function afterFind() {
        parent::afterFind(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        $this->testField .= ' add some calc data';
    }
}
```

и затем

```
<?= GridViewAdvanced::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $testDataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',            
        'testField'
    ],
]); ?>
```